# Why does importing a module executes all statements in python?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

This is my module:

**test1.py**

```
regions=["a","b","c"]
print "from test1 module"
```

**test2.py**

```
from test1 import regions
print "from test2 module", regions
```

**Running the test2.py**

```
$ python test2.py

# this is the output of the execution
from test1 module
from test2 module ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I see that the `print` statement from `test1.py` is called, although I only import `regions` list from `test1.py`. I have not used the instruction `import test1` which cause everything to be executed.

1. why does it execute everything in `test1.py` file (of course not the code under the instruction `if __name__==__main__` if included).
2. How to just `import` the `regions` list from `test1` without executing all the other statements?

I did not know this is how import works and I have been working on a bug due to this for 3 days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is just how imports work.

```
def my_function():
    print("Hello")
```

What is the above snippet of code?  It is a function definition for sure, but function definitions in Python are statements, and they must be *executed* in order to define the function.  So when you import the above module, it *executes* the `def`, which creates a new function and assigns it to `my_function`.  It's basically the same as:

```
my_function = ...definition..
```

So when you import a module, you *always* execute its contents.  Otherwise you wouldn't be able to use any functions (or classes) in that module.

There are other ways to define functions in Python for sure.

```
def create_my_function(x):
    def local_function():
        print(x)
    global my_function
    my_function = local_function

create_my_function("Hello")
```

This is broadly equivalent to the original definition of `my_function()`.

Since you can put any statements in a Python module, Python has no way of knowing which statements must be executed in order to define the symbols you are interested in.  So it must execute all the statements.

Comment: if I import a module, I import the function into the current namespace. I thought that should apply when I import constants. while it does so, it executes other statements in the imported module. is there a way,I could just import constants. I dont want to redeclare constants in all my modules

Comment: so the best way is to have a file dedicated for constants (and avoid inline statements)?

Comment: @eagertoLearn: You can easily import only constants, e.g., `from mymodule import MYCONST`.  However, this **must** cause all top level statements in `mymodule` to be executed, because that is how the constants get their definitions.

Comment: @eagertoLearn: It is considered exceptionally bad practice to have top-level statements with any side effects in Python.  It should be safe to import any module without worrying about what gets executed.

Answer (score 5):

Python needs to execute all statements in a module because they may have related side effects. For example consider

```
a = 2
b = a*3
```

What happens if I import b from that module?
In general, modules other than main should not have side effects that are harmful when imported.  In general modules should define classes, functions and variables, but should not do things like open files, connect to databases etc.

Comment: how to import only constants. I don't want to redeclare everywhere.

Comment: @eagertoLearn: You can import only constants very easily.  However, you cannot avoid executing statements.  Constants are defined using statements, so if you don't execute the statements, you don't get the constants.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way import works - python executes the module when importing. This has it's uses as you can include functionality to validate dependencies, or initialise functionality before the importing module actually invokes any of the classes.